# I keep getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 500

Tags: java, arrays

I keep getting an error that the array is out of bounds and I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
    int[] oddArray = new int[500];//holds all the odd numbers
    int[] primeArray = new int[500];//holds all the prime numbers
    int[] modArray = new int[500];//holds all the mod values
    int remainder, p = 0, x = 0;        

    //fills up the oddArray & modArray
    for(int n = 0; n < 500; n++)
    { 
        oddArray[n] = (n * 2) + 1;
        modArray[n] = (n* 2) + 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i  < 500; i++)
    {

        //finds prime numbers
        for(int n = 0 ; n < 500; n++)
        {   
            //divides the odd numbers by the current mod value
            remainder = oddArray[n] % modArray[x]; 

            //if remainder is not 0 it will place a value in prime array
            if(remainder != 0)
            {
                 primeArray[p] = oddArray[n];
                 p++; 
            }
        }

        //prints out list of odds/mod/and primes side by side
        System.out.println(oddArray[i] + " | " + modArray[i] + " | " + primeArray[p]);
        ++x;
    }
```

This is the error code

> 1 | 1 | 0
>
> 3 | 3 | 0
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 500
>      at projectprime_v1.ProjectPrime_V1.main(ProjectPrime_V1.java:41)
>      Java Result: 1
>      BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to a) determine which line has the problem and b) what the values of the variables you are using to index the arrays are?

Comment: see the  updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You are never resetting `p`, so eventually it will exceed 499, and cause the exception. Make sure that inside your loop to write `p = 0;` to reset it. The same goes for `x`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or at the top of the loop.  First run it will already be 0, but who cares.

Comment: @Draco18s Right. As long as it's reset somewhere in the loop.